# Magento Add Multiple Buttons to Sale Order View

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I have a file extending Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_View:

NameSpace_Module_Block_Sales_Order_View

Within it:

```
public function  __construct() {

    parent::__construct();

    $_label = Mage::helper('sales')->__('Button 1');
    $this->_addButton('button_one', array(
        'label'     => $_label,
        'onclick'   => $omittedJs,
        'class'     => 'go'
    ),0,15);

    $_label = Mage::helper('sales')->__('Button 2');
    $this->_addButton('button_two', array(
        'label'     => $_label,
        'onclick'   => $omittedJs,
        'class'     => 'go'
    ),0,15);
}
```

For some reason, only Button 2 will display, if I remove Button 2, Button 1 will display.

How can I get both buttons to show up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following instead of your code.

```
$_label = Mage::helper('sales')->__('Button 1');
$this->_addButton('button_one', array(
    'label'     => $_label,
    'onclick'   => $omittedJs,
    'class'     => 'go'
),0,15);

$_label = Mage::helper('sales')->__('Button 2');
$this->_addButton('button_two', array(
    'label'     => $_label,
    'onclick'   => $omittedJs,
    'class'     => 'go'
),0,16);
```

Last argument in _addButton defines position. It was same in your code